# Port forwarding from non-default internet connection

Tags: routing, port-forwarding

I have two outgoing connections, pointing to different ISPs, on a gateway, in front of small-ish LAN.

IPs addresses are as follows:

ISP 1:

- network: 10.1.1.0/24
- gateway ip: 10.1.1.1
- client ip: 10.1.1.2 (eth1)

ISP 2:

- network: 10.2.1.0/24
- gateway ip: 10.2.1.1
- client ip: 10.2.1.2 (eth2)

LAN:

- network: 192.168.0.0/24
- gateway ip: 192.168.0.1 (eth0)

Few LAN clients, with IPs in range 192.168.0.128/25.

So, essentially, gateway has IPs `10.1.1.2`, `10.2.1.2`, and `192.168.0.1` on 3 NICs.

Default route on gateway is set to 10.1.1.1 dev eth1.

Right now, I have one routing table consisting of following entries, named `isp2`:

- network 192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0
- network 10.2.1.0/24 dev eth2
- default route 10.2.1.1 dev eth2

I use that `isp2` in MANGLE rules to redirect some traffic to utilize second outgoing link.

Everything works fine, when I want to redirect traffic that goes OUT, if it will go over primary ISP or over secondary ISP, based on MANGLE table rules.

**Question**: How do I configure gateway so it would allow inbound connections from second ISP, to be forwarded to clients in LAN, behind gateway? I want to forward traffic incoming on specific ports to specific port of specific clients, but it has to work over non-default route.

Any ideas?

Platform that I use is irrelevant, I'm more interested what needs to be done in order for this to work, but you can write examples as if I were using linux (so iproute2/iptables).

Comment: You want some machines on your LAN to be reachable from the ISP2 WAN? Do those machines have public ip addresses? NAT perhaps?

Comment: @sims: no. they don't have public IPs, they are NATed. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: So you want some machines, say an ftp server, to be accessible from the "internet" via the secondary WAN (your secondary ISP provider)?

Comment: @sims: Yes, that would be a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use rinetd.

For FTP forwarding via ISP2, while ISP1 is the default one.

oneliner config:

10.2.1.2:21 192.168.1.129:21

the downside: on your FTP log, all connections will appear as coming from 10.2.1.2